sorting vector of string of dates in C++
I found that code:
  sort(filenames.begin(), filenames.end(), [](const string& a, const string& b)
    {
        auto getEpochTime = [](const string& s) -> time_t
        {
            std::string a = s.substr(s.find("trades") + 7, 10);
            std::istringstream date_s(a);
            struct tm date_c;
            date_s >> std::get_time( &date_c, "%Y-%m-%d" );

            std::time_t seconds = std::mktime( & date_c );
            return seconds;
        };

        time_t partA = getEpochTime(a), partB = getEpochTime(b);
        //time_t partA = GetDate(a), partB = GetDate(b);
        cout << a << " " << partA << " " << partB << " " << b << endl;
        return partA < partB;
    });

my filenames is a vector with those values:
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-01.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-03.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-04.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-08.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-05.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-06.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-09.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-10.csv

And as you can see, after the sorting, it clearly did not work. For some reason, when printing a and partA inside the sorting function, I find weird values:
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-09.csv 1578525308 1577834108 ./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-01.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-09.csv 1536583284 1578400884 ./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-07.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-09.csv 1578573684 1578660084 ./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-10.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-09.csv 1578573684 1578314484 ./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-06.csv
./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-02.csv -504396806053 1577834108 ./files/BTCUSDT-trades-2020-01-01.csv


Some dates give negative values
Same dates (2020-01-09 for instance) give different values (1578525308, 1536583284).

Any idea what I did wrong please?

What does getEpochTime do?   It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: How to debug small programs and Debugging Guide

Just as a comment before I actually read the code, those dates appear to be yyyy-mm-dd, so you can just sort them as strings. I prefer iso format, mostly for that reason.

@NathanOliver my bad, just that I changed to name last minute, so it's the same function

Short answer - don't use any time conversion, you can simply sort the strings lexicographically:
std::sort(filenames.begin(), filenames.end());


Long answer - you failed to initialise properly your std::tm object, so it contains garbage values.
From the documentation of std::mktime:

If the std::tm object was obtained from std::get_time or the POSIX strptime, the value of tm_isdst is indeterminate, and needs to be set explicitly before calling mktime.

And from the documentation for std::get_time:

[...] it's unspecified if this function zero out the fields in *tmb that are not set directly by the conversion specifiers that appear in fmt: portable programs should initialize every field of *tmb to zero before calling std::get_time.

You have to initialise everything that is not set by std::get_time:
// ...
struct tm date_c;
date_c.tm_sec = 0;
date_c.tm_min = 0;
date_c.tm_hour = 0;
date_c.tm_isdst = 0;
date_s >> std::get_time( &date_c, "%Y-%m-%d" );
// ...


Or simpler: tm date_c = {};
